# Call using Skype.app via openURL:

Tags: iphone, ios, skype, uiapplication

Does anybody know if it is possible open Skype.app to call phone via

```
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url
```

UIApplication message?

If it possible, what url a need pass to this message?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for reference, this seems to have changed when multitasking support was added: starting at least with Skype 2.1.0, this URI works fine: `skype:+33123456789?call`

Comment: Great news! I'll remove my outdated answer!

Comment: Can I open chat in skype with specified account? And if them not added to my list ?

Answer (score 4):

By looking at Skype's Info.plist file (you can open it from the ipa file iTunes has downloaded), you can tell it has no URL registered, so you won't be able to call it from your application.

You should look for a key called `CFBundleURLTypes` (you can look at Twiterrific's for an app that has one defined).

**Update**: Apparently, starting with Skype 2.1, there is a URL registered. See other answers on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide some direction here we provide URI support on iOS and we have created an example for you, see: https://dev.skype.com/skype-uri/skype-uri-tutorial-ios

Comment: The link is outdated. This is why link-only answers are inappropriate on SO.