# iPhone app link to open skype

Tags: iphone, skype

Is there a way to encode links in an iPhone app that will launch skype if installed on the phone? This would be similar to email, maps and phone.

Any samples would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243810/call-using-skype-app-via-openurl).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but im still not clear if there is a straightforward way to do this or not.

anybody know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to build a sample project for this with the team. Here you go

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2982102/SkypeCallTest.zip

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ?call - if you append the video=true it stops working, even though the documentation says it works.